# Html Canvas : difference between width/height attribute and width/height style

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have seen various answers on canvas resize but could not understand the problem I am facing. Following is the canvas element rendered on my web app.

```
Before Rendering: 

    <canvas id="g_5" resize></canvas>

After Rendering:

     <canvas id="g_5"  resize width="1076" height="306" style="-webkit-user-select: none; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 1148.38px; height: 300px;"></canvas>
```

I am setting height and width of canvas as follows:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var width = <someWidth>;  //=1076 in this case
        var height = <someHeight>; //=306 in this case
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
```

After doing this, width/height in style supersedes the attribute width/height and hence canvas uses style's height/width.

My questions are:

1. Why there are two different width/height?
2. How to set them to have same value
3. If I remove `resize` attribute from canvas element, canvas size stays to default size.

Answer (score 1):

1. Setting width/height in html attributes is being applied first until the css is loaded.
2. After css is loaded the width/height attributes is ignored and use its style definition.
3. After using the javascript resize code then you'll get the canvas resized in that event.

Comment: How to ignore point# 2, I want to use attribute width and height for the canvas.

Comment: Then remove the style css width/height.

Comment: I am not adding style css in my code, it is getting added by default.

Comment: If so some scripting is causing you that.