# Unable to get Canvas on screen via HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my code, I am getting only black canvas of defined width and height. And Red and white is not rendering on screen.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var canvas;
var canvasContext;
var ballx = 50;

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  drawCanvas();
  drawCanvasRed();
  // drawCanvas();
}

function drawCanvas() {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
  canvasContext.fillRect(225, 200, 50, 25);
};

function drawCanvasRed() {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
  canvasContext.fillRect(ballx, 200, 50, 25);
}
```

```css
#gameCanvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It works, they are just "outside" of the canvas. If you don't define the size of a canvas it uses 300x150px as default size.

Comment: @cloned Why did you modify OPs code (adding the style definition)?

Comment: @Andreas The canvas size is defined in css file, as 800x600 px

Comment: This does not affect the actual size of the canvas -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219815/html-canvas-difference-between-width-height-attribute-and-width-height-style

Comment: @Andreas. It is working now when inline styling is given. thanks for explanation.

Comment: You might want to add (and accept) your working solution as answer (or delete your question) to complete this question.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, just wanted to set some default width/height, I thought since the 220 other drawings were at 250 position, 500 is good to go. but apparently I screwed up here, sorry for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the size of the canvas. I have changed some sizes. So it's could help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <style>
      #gameCanvas {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
      <script>
         var canvas;
         var canvasContext;
         var ballx = 50;

         window.onload = function() {
           canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
           canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
           drawCanvas();
           drawCanvasRed();
           // drawCanvas();
         }

         function drawCanvas() {
           canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
           canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500); // In your size you need to check, because you passed canvas width and canvas height

           canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
           canvasContext.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 25);
         };

         function drawCanvasRed() {

           canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
           canvasContext.fillRect(ballx, 50, 50, 25);
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```